# Changed all configs, but why is Heroku continuing to use Ruby- 2.0.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, heroku-toolbelt

I have added Ruby 2.1.5 to my gem file, and after that failed, also added e ruby version to the config vars.

But when deploying, it continues to show that we are using 2.0.0

```
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using 1.7.12
```

Then it fails because of modware:

```
remote:        Gem::InstallError: modware requires Ruby version >= 2.1.0.
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
Gemfile
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
    ruby "2.1.5"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Type this in your terminal :

```
heroku config -s | grep PATH
```

Then, if you get something like

```
PATH=vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

You need to add "bin:" before "vendor" in the PATH, with this command line :

```
heroku config:set PATH=bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

Source : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions#troubleshooting

Comment: thank you! tried it, but exact same problem. must be some really silly n00b error